brightness is set to maximum whenever i log in in Ubuntu 24.04

whenever i log in the brightness is reset to maximum,
this means I close the laptop and reopen it, the brightness is set to maximum
earlier there was no issue like this
i think the bug is introduced in ubuntu 24.04


can someone raise this as a bug on ubuntu bug traker

This is one of the oldest bugs in Ubuntu that has never been solved. I remember raising a ticket for it back in 2009. Nothing came of it. I am afraid you just have to live with it until you change your hardware (mainly motherboard) that is compatible with Ubuntu.

It is fixed now

I've just installed Ubuntu 24.04 and among some other issues, I have this problem. How to fix it? Thanks.

Use enter brightnessctl
sudo apt install brightnessctl

The value of brightness is stored in /sys/class/backlight/*/brightness. The value is between 0 to 255, with 0 being the minimum brightness and 255 being the maximum.
You can set the brightness using brightnessctl:

sudo brightnessctl set 50% to set the brightness to 50%
sudo brightnessctl set +5% to increase the brightness by 5%

The problem is that it requires sudo permission. We can fix this by changing the permissions of /sys/class/backlight/*/brightness by:
sudo chmod o+w /sys/class/backlight/*/brightness

And now you can run brightnessctl set 20% without sudo.
Now when your computer starts, a script runs called /etc/rc.local
Just add the command to this file and you are done.
TLDR:

sudo apt install brightnessctl
sudo chmod o+w /sys/class/backlight/*/brightness
sudo sed -i '$ a brightnessctl set 20%' /etc/rc.local

Good luck.
